# switch videoview to fullscreen mode android

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview

I want to display a videoview in fullscreen mode when the user press a full screen button
I have searched on the internet but all solutions I have found doesnt' fix the issue

here is my current code which doesnt' work too :

```
        public void setAnchorView(final View view) {
        super.setAnchorView(view);

        Button fullScreen = new Button(VideoDetails.this);
        fullScreen.setText("FullScreen");
        Log.e("media controller","Set anchorView");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(view.getWidth(), 0, 5, 20);
        params.gravity =  Gravity.RIGHT;
        addView(fullScreen, params);

        fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                 android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoview.getLayoutParams();

                 params.leftMargin = 0;
                 videoview.setLayoutParams(params);



            }
        });
            }
```

and here is the xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#818181" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_details_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="returnback"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_details_text_header_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/video_details_header"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_page"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_details_video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_details_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="showvideo"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_details_videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

which contains the videoview

do you have any idea

Comment: Have you found any solution to play video in fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Try [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) call after setting the layout params

```
             ...
             params.leftMargin = 0;
             videoview.setLayoutParams(params);
             videoview.requestLayout();
```

Comment: unfortunetly, nothing happen some issue

Answer (score 0):

try to change the width of the view too:

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)videoview.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int displayWidth = display.getWidth();

    params.leftMargin = 0;
    params.width = displayWidth;
    videoview.setLayoutParams(params);
    videoview.requestLayout();
```

Not sure because can't all code, but for me  it seems like you don't need setting margin at all
you may just manipulate with view's width and gravity.

Comment: yep, it should not work until you change visibility to View.GONE of all other controls which take place on the screen. Height of FrameLayout with id @+id/video_details_video should be changed too.
In my opinion it would be much better to implement your own class with custom layouting, interited from ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten this line of code for it to fit the full screen.

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score -1):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
             android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
             params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
             params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
             params.leftMargin = 0;
             videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```